# Google Street View API High resolution image without premium

Tags: google-street-view

For our project i need resolution higher than 640x640, it is for printing purposes. I need the Street View of 2000 addresses, i was sent here by Google to solve the problem because Google said premium for this project is expensive (8000 euros a year) and someone would come with a different solution than buying premium.

Comment: @MartinHoogstraten what do you mean by printing? Do you physically mean printing on paper? What resolution do you need? Just higher than 640x640? Also where are the imagery locations you seek?